# Using multiple int array as args

Tags: java, arrays, function, int, args

Here is the problem: 
I have 3 int [] as args and I need to pass them to the function that works with them.
The args[] are:

```
 1: {14,14,17,17,14,12,13,11,12}
 2: {74,34,57,67,34,42,53,61,22}
 3: {24,24,12,21,29,14,21,17,12}
```

As for source idea:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("amount: " + args.length);
        int[] intArray = new int[args.length];
        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
             intArray[i]=Integer.valueOf(args[i]);
        int[] statica= intArray[0];
        int[] inserta= intArray[1];
        int[] reservea= intArray[2];

    GraphicConsts.getSvgStylTotalamount();
    InputValues inputValues = new InputValues(statica, inserta, reservea);
    inputValues.init();
}
```

}

the inputValues:

```
public class InputValues {

private int[] staticamount; 

public int[] insertamount;

private int[] reserveamount;

private int[] totalamount=new int[]{};
private int[] depositDF=new int[]{};
private int[] depositelse=new int[]{};

public InputValues(int statica, int inserta, int reservea) {

// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
    public void init() {

// AUTO generated setters und getters

}
```

This whole thing goes through a FOPConverter but that part is working. 
This whole thing works, if I hardcode the arrays like

```
private int[] staticamount= new int[]{14,14,17,17,14,12,13,11,12};
```

but I need those to be the args.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not really clear what you are doing. How do you call/run your program ?

Comment: I think he is going to run it by calling it's main method only. But, he has not mentioned it.

Comment: I suggest using an english naming convention. Many will have difficulties reading this code. In the end, it will also help you because more people can/will help you. ;)

Comment: Yes I call the main with 3 args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to use only 3 args where each arg used as list. Well, you can use GSON package and pass arguments like single strings. Here is example:

Inputs:

arg1: `[14,14,17,17,14,12,13,11,12]`

arg2: `[74,34,57,67,34,42,53,61,22]`

arg3: `[24,24,12,21,29,14,21,17,12]`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
....
public static void main(String[] args) {

....

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<int[]>(){}.getType();

int[] festmengeNew1 = gson.fromJson(args[0], collectionType); 
int[] festmengeNew2 = gson.fromJson(args[1], collectionType); 
int[] festmengeNew3 = gson.fromJson(args[2], collectionType); 
....
}
```

As you see I entered 3 parameters as String and converted to list of `int`. Suppose it will help you

Comment: On this I get: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static methode fromJson(String, Type) from the Type Gson`

Comment: add `Gson gson = new Gson();`

Comment: take a look on what I posted above: I used `[14,14,17,17,14,12,13,11,12]`, not `{...}`.    Your inputs should be: "[14,14,17,17,14,12,13,11,12]" "[74,34,57,67,34,42,53,61,22]" "[24,24,12,21,29,14,21,17,12]"

Comment: Yes, `GSON` uses `{...}` as list of Objects and `[...]` as list of values. Use brackets `[]` instead braces `{}`

Comment: The function is `public InputValues(int[] statica int[] inserta, int[] reservea) { `  The setter is `public void setinsertamount(int[] inserta) {
  this.insertamount= inserta;
 }`... that should work right?

Comment: sure, since you converted String to `int[]` , all should work the same

Comment: Pinting them out brings: `[I@1abc7b9` and the calculations don't works as if the int[] are not being passed on as values... I need the hardcoded: `new int[]{14,14,17,17,14,12,13,11,12}` to be replaced with the setter... can it be that the setter set the adr not the value and therefore the cals don't work ... do I have to do something specific to the the values passed on?

Answer (score 0):

main(String args[]) always requires an array of type String. It does not allow you to pass array of array, as is your requirement. So,what you can do is pass each array as a comma separated string, then split each string with delimiter as ','. You will be able to retrieve your array.